# Poem from a teacher: "There is a tree I love // And she loves me // Sentient beings call her home"

Tags: identification-request, poetry

> There is a tree I love
> And she loves me
> Sentient beings call her home,
> She is their world
> Their womb of God
> Knowing only here.
> She sings out the perfection
> The rightness, the holy stillness of all life.
> She says don't be afraid.
> It is all unfolding as it should
>
> But I am scared.
> She reminds me:
> You don't begin or end.
> You are, you were and you will be
> Stardust sparkles in your eyes.
> The planets occupy your bones
> Once upon a time
> You were split about the universe
>
> I am the breeze that sings its way into me,
> I am the sunshine smiling on me,
> I am  the rain that quenches me,
> I am the food that enters my roots,
> No boundary between life and life.
> Expand outside of me,
> Swirl around me,
> Dance across the field to you.
> Through the fence and kiss you.
> You breathe in a little of me,
> I breathe in a little of you.
>
> And when you leave this place,
> I will not mourn your return home
> from where you came.
> I will continue to reach upwards, outwards
> In celebration forever
> Of the beautiful miracle of you,
> Of me, of all life.

The only other text on the page is:

> Reading - There is a Tree - Mago

This poem was given to me several years ago by a teacher of mine. I have no idea where it came from, but I would love to know!

Comment: You mention a "page" - are there illustrations? Does this come with other poems (e.g. in a collection)? If so, could you provide information about the collection? Was this given as an assignment or in another context?

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s just a blank A4 piece of paper with the words printed on. It wasn’t an assignment or anything either - I’m pretty sure she just gave it to me because she thought I’d like it.